# RMI Exception RemoteException nested exception

Tags: java, rmi, netbeans-7

Trying to run RMI example but facing the following exception:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hejsan.RemoteBuffer
```

I have started the rmiregristry and it seems to be running fine. But the server is not running, it just builds and stops. 
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/rmiregistry`

**Project name:** hej 
**Package name:** hejsan 
**Files:** MyBuffer.java and RemoteBuffer.java

MyBuffer.java:

```
package hejsan;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.LinkedList;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyBuffer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteBuffer {

    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public MyBuffer() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
        super();
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/buffer", this);
    }

    public synchronized void put(Integer i) throws RemoteException {
        list.addLast(i);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized Integer get() throws RemoteException {
        while (list.size() == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return (Integer) list.removeFirst();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new MyBuffer();
        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            System.out.println(re);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            System.out.println(me);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

RemoteBuffer.java:

```
package hejsan;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface RemoteBuffer extends Remote {
    void put(Integer i) throws RemoteException;
    Integer get() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had to be on netbeans project path: `~/build/classes` and runs the rmiregistry from while on that path. 

The rmiregistry path can be found under *Tools-> Java Platforms* in netbeans. Caution! Change to jre instead of jdk following this below example: 
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/rmiregistry`